# Timer convenience class to time code execution for user output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I implemented a convenience class to time code execution and print it to the user. This is part of a bigger project that will be distributed to external users. The timer however is only called by other procedures, not by the user directly. I was interested in implementing this myself, so I'm not looking for an external module or similiar. Docstrings are omitted here, the functions are rather straightforward.

```
from time import perf_counter


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, default_round_digits: int = 5):
        self.default_digits = default_round_digits
        self.start_timer()

    def start_timer(self) -> None:
        self.start_time = perf_counter()
        self.pause_start_time = None
        self.pause_length = 0

    def pause_timer(self) -> None:
        self.pause_start_time = perf_counter()

    def resume_timer(self) -> None:
        if self.pause_start_time is not None:
            self.pause_length += perf_counter() - self.pause_start_time
            self.pause_start_time = None

    @property
    def elapsed_seconds(self) -> float:
        # If timer is paused only consider time up to self.pause_start_time instead of now
        if self.pause_start_time is not None:
            return self.pause_start_time - self.start_time - self.pause_length
        else:
            return perf_counter() - self.start_time - self.pause_length

    def get_timer(self, round_digits: int = None, print_text: str = None, restart: bool = False) -> float:

        if round_digits is None:
            round_digits = self.default_digits

        elapsed_seconds = round(self.elapsed_seconds, ndigits=round_digits)

        if print_text is not None:
            print(f"{print_text}{elapsed_seconds} seconds")

        if restart:
            self.start_timer()

        return elapsed_seconds

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        state = "Running" if self.pause_start_time is None else "Paused"
        return f"{state} Timer at {self.get_timer()} seconds"
```

I'm still unsure about initializing attributes outside of `__init__`. I know it's not recommended, but copying `start_timer` into `__init__` seemed like the worse option to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `Timer` class contains two timers.

   1. The entire duration timer.
   2. The timer for tracking pauses.

   I'd move the core timer code out into a separate class.
   And we can see you're starting to repeat yourself.
2. Initializing a timer shouldn't start the timer.
   If I open my timer app should the timer start running straight away?

   If I want to create some timers but I don't want the timer to be started your class gives me no options.
   However just not calling `start_timer` in `__init__` will allow everyone to use your class however is desired.

   If you really really want to start the timer when building the object, you can write a class method.

   ```
   class Timer:
       @classmethod
       def run(cls, *args, **kwargs):
           self = cls(*args, **kwargs)
           self.start_timer()
           return self

   # option 1
   timer = Timer()
   timer.start_timer()

   # option 2
   timer = Timer.run()
   ```
3. `start_timer` restarts the timers.
   You should rename the method or make the method do what is expected.
4. If you call `pause_timer` twice without calling `resume_timer` your code acts as if the timer was never paused the first time.
5. I don't really see the point of making `elapsed_seconds` a property.
6. `get_timer` is doing way too much and violates the SRP principle.

   1. Rounds elapsed timings to a specified amount of decimal places.
   2. Prints the elapsed timings.
   3. Restarts the timer.
   4. Returns the elapsed timings.

   You should make a function to round the elapsed timings.
   Then leave printing and restarting to the user.
7. I'd a couple more methods from functionality I'd expect from a timer.

```py
from time import perf_counter


class CoreTimer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop()

    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.start_time)

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = perf_counter()

    def stop(self):
        self.start_time = 0

    def time_taken(self, now):
        return now - self.start_time

    def elapsed(self):
        return self.time_taken(perf_counter())


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, decimal_places=5):
        self._decimal_places = decimal_places
        self._timer = CoreTimer()
        self._pause = CoreTimer()
        self._pause_length = 0

    def __str__(self):
        state = "Paused" if self._pause else "Running"
        return f"{state} Timer at {self.elapsed_rounded()} seconds"

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start()
        return self

    def start(self):
        if not self._timer:
            self._timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.stop()
        self._pause.stop()
        self._pause_length = 0

    def restart(self):
        self.stop()
        self.start()

    def pause(self):
        if not self._pause:
            self._pause.start()

    def resume(self):
        if self._pause:
            self._pause_length += self._pause.elapsed()
            self._pause.stop()

    def elapsed(self):
        if self._pause:
            duration = self._timer.time_taken(self._pause.start_time)
        else:
            duration = self._timer.elapsed()
        return duration - self._pause_length

    def elapsed_rounded(self, decimal_places=None):
        if decimal_places is None:
            decimal_places = self.decimal_places
        return round(self.elapsed(), ndigits=decimal_places)
```

Comment: Thank you for your perspective, this is really helpful (a lot of improvements I hadn't considered yet)! I should've specified, that the timer will not be used directly by the user, only the print-outs by `get_timer` are seen by the user. That's why I included as much convenience for myself as possible. Considering that, would you still advise against the existence of convenience methods for printing and restarting? Something like `print_elapsed_and_restart`?

Comment: @riskypenguin By "the user" I mean "anyone who uses `Timer`" not "anyone who uses your library". I can understand the desire for convenience. But many times what you think is convenient at the start of the project is an inconvenience by the end of the project.

Comment: I see your point, thanks again for the comprehensive review!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question about attribute initialization:

It's not necessarily better to put all attributes into `__init__`. It's generally recommended, since we expect to find all class attributes inside of `__init__`, but I would argue in this case, it's just as readable. In fact I would say initializing these values with `None` inside `__init__` (just to suppress the warnings or follow the recommendation) hurts readability in your case:

```
def __init__(self, default_round_digits: int = 5):
    self.default_digits = default_round_digits

    self.start_time = None
    self.pause_start_time = None
    self.pause_length = None

    self.start_timer()
```

Here are some further discussions on StackOverflow regarding the topic:

- [Instance attribute attribute_name defined outside **init**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284857/instance-attribute-attribute-name-defined-outside-init)
- [Python - instance attribute defined outside **init**()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434475/python-instance-attribute-defined-outside-init)
- [why is defining an object variable outside of **init** frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158898/why-is-defining-an-object-variable-outside-of-init-frowned-upon/25159060)